# How to enable babel stage-0 in webpack config file

Tags: reactjs, web-config, babeljs, react-dom

I used the below-mentioned command:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0
```

Now I added it in webpack.config.js file as shown below:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './app/app.jsx',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './public/bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        root: __dirname,
        alias: {

        },
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
                },
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

But Now when I run webpack command it shows some error. Please check error:

Error image:

[image]

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: @FunkSoulNinja Please click on Error image link in question to view error.

Comment: @FunkSoulNinja I tried your solution but same error. Please check error.

Comment: I have no idea as to what the problem may be. Perhaps make sure you are used the lastest version of both webpack and node. Update them if not and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using a .babelrc file, add babelrc: false like so:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            babelrc: false, // <--- Add this
            query: {
                presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
            },
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
        }
    ]
}
```

I recommend using the [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) CLI if you don't want to deal with the headache of setting up a development environment boilerplate. I just started using it and it is great!